# Does this property have a name?

Tags: order-theory

When I have a set of numbers such as $\Bbb Z$ and say I have some $n\in \Bbb Z$, if I put some lower and upper bounds on $n$, that is $a>n>b$, then there are finite options for $n$.

Does this property, or sets that posses this property have a name?

Comment: This would appear to be a property of an ordering of a set, rather than a property of the set.

Answer (score 3):

An ordering with this property is called [locally finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_poset).

A *total* locally finite ordering will be either finite or order-isomorphic to one of $(\mathbb Z,{<})$, $(\mathbb N,{<})$, or $(\mathbb N,{>})$. There are more possibilities for a locally finite *partial* ordering, though.